# $watchCollection at the ui grid filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to connect table (ui grid) with another view in Angular using $watchCollection function.
I need $watchCollection to watch textbox (filter area) in the table and when changes are identified the text is whittled down based on the filter values.

I've defined UI grid `<div ui-grid="gridOptions" ng-model="query" ui-grid-selection class="grid"></div>` and now I'm trying to $watch whole array (filters) in the table using $watchCollection:

```
 $scope.$watchCollection("query", function(newList, oldList) {
       $scope.newList = newList;
       $scope.oldList = oldList;
    });
```

When I write in the filter, there is nothing changes.. 
Please take a look at the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9uqBZEEcf0pzhz5TojPG?p=preview), what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your plunkr does not have this logic inside it?

Comment: Please take a look at the main.html for table definition. Logic is defined in script.js

Comment: Your script.js just has a config and a controller with 2 scope variables in it. There is no watch collection logic int he plunkr you have linked in your question.

Comment: Please take a look at the v11. I've edited the link immediately after posting question.

Answer (score 1):

Add true to find any value change in the list

```
$scope.$watchCollection("query", function(newList, oldList) {
   $scope.newList = newList;
   $scope.oldList = oldList;
}, true);
```